# Migrate Parent-Child tables from one server to another using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a parent table and child table in one server which is related by ParentId in child table. I need to migrate these table to new server.
In destination both parent and child will have new Identity col as PK and parent child relation with FK. I don't want to insert the PKs from Source to the destination because when we start insert into the destination tables from the application the PKs from source col will be null. To keep the reference I need to insert the Identity col from source table and destination table to a new table. Following is the table structure I am trying to achieve

### SourceParent

| ParentID | ParentName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

### SourceChild

| ChildID | ParentID | ChildName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AA |
| 2 | 1 | AB |
| 3 | 2 | BA |

### DestParent

| NewParentID | ParentName |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | A |
| 102 | B |

### DestChild

| NewChildID | NewParentID | ChildName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 101 | AA |
| 102 | 101 | AB |
| 103 | 102 | BA |

### Ref Table in Destination Server

| SourceTableName | DestinationTableName | SourceTablePK | DestinationTablePK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SourceParent | DestParent | 1 | 101 |
| SourceParent | DestParent | 2 | 102 |
| SourceChild | DestChild | 1 | 101 |
| SourceChild | DestChild | 2 | 102 |
| SourceChild | DestChild | 3 | 103 |

I am trying to achieve this using SSIS

Any recommended method to achieve these scenario in SSIS.

TIA